# Negative pipe matching with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I have a string called, say, `"I will kill you today"` or something like that.
I want to match all of the words that are not 'kill' or 'will'. I believe negative character classes will not work, because this is for a word. I have looked at negative lookaheads, but I don't quite know how to use them.

In other words, when I input

```
"I will kill you today"
```

I want

```
['I', 'you', 'today']
```

when I pass the `findall` method.

Comment: Are you specifically interested in matching words (tokens separated by white-space)? Because then you could simply apply a logical NOT to the result of matching a regular regular expression. (Or simply ask `word in words` where `words` is a `set` of strings.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you may use alternation operator.

```
re.findall(r'\b(?:[kw]ill)\b|\b(\w+)\b', s)
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "I will kill you today"
>>> [i for i in re.findall(r'\b(?:[kw]ill)\b|\b(\w+)\b', s) if i]
['I', 'you', 'today']
```

Comment: I'd like to use an expression regardless of the word I'm matching. Does this expression match, say, 'today' and 'you' if you modify the code?

Comment: ya, did you check that?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you need a regex for that. Just `split()` the string and filter out the words you're not interested in:

```
s = "I will kill you today"
result = [word for word in s.split() if word.lower() not in ('kill', 'will')]
```

Result:

```
>>> result
['I', 'you', 'today']
```

Comment: Actually, it's part of a URL thing. I need to identify a URL, but I decided to use another example for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: In that case, your question's sample input and output - the whole thing, really - are misleading (missing the C in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Accept the answer that answers the question you ended up actually asking, and then ask a new question.

Comment: Perfectly fine with me.